# Running npm install on Ubuntu with Octopus Deploy

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, octopus-deploy

We are using Octopus deploy to deploy an angularjs app. I'm running a post deployment script (bash) and in there I try to do `npm install`. This doesn't work, I get an error

```
npm: command not found
```

However if I login to the linux box as the Octopus user, go to the directory that Octopus Deploy is trying to run the script from, I am able to run `npm install` without error.

I've confirmed its the right user (running `whoami` before `npm install` in the post deployment script).

I've tried adding the npm executable to my PATH variables which didn't work. I've also put the full path to npm in my script which gives me a new error

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run the following command as octopus user to access npm for other users.

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Or use nvm to install node

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash

source ~/.bashrc

source ~/.profile

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  


nvm ls-remote

nvm install 8.10.0 

node --version

npm --version

which node

n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

If you are installing new node version, please do the following steps.

`nvm list`     will show all installed node versions

`nvm use v8.10.0`

`nvm alias default v8.10.0`     set default node version for current user

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Do I need to run the copy command each time I install new modules or update node?